# How can I avoid entering strings for known keys in C#

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
switch(first)
{
    case 'A':
        vm.Content = contentService.Get("0001000", vm.RowKey);
        return View("Article", vm);
    case 'F':
        vm.Content = contentService.Get("0002000", vm.RowKey);
        return View("FavoritesList", vm);
}
```

'A' refers to a page type of Article with a key of "0001000"
'F' refers to a page type of Favorite with a key of "0002000"

Is there a way in C# that I could avoid having to code in the keys as a string?
Some way that would allow me to code in by the key abbreviation or name
and then have C# convert this to a string?

Can I use Enum for this?  This seems ideal but I am not sure how to set up an Enum.

Comment: Yes, you can. Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use enums and use extension methods to allow an alternative text output.

The enum:

```
public enum PageTypes
{
    A,
    F
}
```

The extension method (needs to be in the top level of your project):

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string getText(this PageTypes type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case PageTypes.A:
                return "0001000";
            case PageTypes.F:
                return "0002000";
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And your code:

```
PageTypes type;
//assing value to type:
//type = ...
var vm.Content = contentService.Get(type.getText(), vm.RowKey);
switch (type)
{
    case PageTypes.A:              
        return View("Article", vm);
    case PageTypes.F:
        return View("FavoritesList", vm);
}
```

Now you do not need to use strings to retrieve the values.

Answer (score 3):

You may think about dictionary (if I right understood your question)

```
//class for holding relation between the code and page name 
public class Data 
{
   public string Code {get;set;}
   public string PageName {get;set;}
}

var dic = new Dictionary<string, Data >{ 
             {"A", new Data{Code="0001000", PageName = "Article"}, 
             {"F", newe Data{Code="0002000", PageName="FavoritesList"}
}
```

and after use it like:

```
Data dt = null; 
if(dic.TryGetValue(first, out dt)) { // *first* is parameter you use in switch
   vm.Content = contentService.Get(dt.Code, vm.RowKey);
   return View(dt.PageName, vm);
 }
```

Comment: But `first` is still a string. According to the question this is exactly what she wants to avoid.

Comment: @Jan: **somewhere** you have to define strings. In example provided you avoid to hardcode them in different places but have them *only* in dictionary. After, that dictionary *may* be populated from some config file, or some other source, but this goes away from the subject of this question, imo.

Comment: yes, you have to define them. But in your example you have to actually use them to reference the value. When you use enums, you do **not** have to use strings. This is what the question explicitly asks for.

Comment: @Jan: don't think that OP's asking about a way do not use strings properly. He is asking about better way of using them, imo, and not useing them in a way presented in question.

Answer (score 0):

I would put the keys in a dictionary, e.g.

```
var keyData = new Dictionary(char,string);
keyData.Add('A',"0001000");

keyData.Add('A',"0001000");
keyData.Add('F',"0002000");
```

You could then reference them using

```
var value = keyData['A'];
```

Comment: It still uses a string to retrieve the value

Comment: Yes.  +1 For @Tigran 's solution, definitely the most elegant.